# How to get value of input type = hidden in javascript?

Tags: jquery

How can I change my code to check for the value of, input type = hidden? 
This is, input type = checkbox

```
var $chk = $("#room_"+conference).find("input[type='checkbox']:checked");
```

Comment: based on the other question you asked you should be able to figure this out for yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the name on the input and look for it within the form

```
var hiddenVal =  $('#myForm input[name="hiddenInputName"]').val();
```

No more complicated than using css selectors. Suggest you read through the [jQuery Selectors API](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)